# Unable to load url in webview

Tags: android, url, webview, android-activity

I'm trying to load a URL in a webview but I keep getting an error. (see below)

this is the code that should load the URL at startup:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    WebView mywebview1;

       mywebview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myownwebview);
       mywebview1.loadUrl("http://www.mad-sharky.com");
}
```

I have a webview in my XML file with id "myownwebview". Whenever i start the projecti get the error message shown in the picture:

[image]

I searched a lot and most of the answers I found tell that the URL is written to the view before it is created and therefore it throws an exception. It is supposed to be after "seContentView". But in my case it is after `setContentView` so I can't find what is causing it.

Debug screen image:

[image]

Comment: please post your LogCat output

Comment: Updated the post! If you need more let me know.. thank you!

Comment: Can you post directly the LogCat? No image, the text.

Comment: I cant find out how to copy it.. onyl thing i can copy is the console output...

Comment: there is not much in the logcat... `E -1 Device disconnected: 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the fragment transaction is causing the exception, so comment this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   /* if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }*/


    WebView mywebview1;

       mywebview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myownwebview);
       mywebview1.loadUrl("http://www.mad-sharky.com");


}
```

or load the url into the WebView from the `PlaceholderFragment`

Comment: are you sure to have the webview "myownwebview" inside your activity_main layout?

Comment: feel pretty stupid right now.. :) i had it in my fragment_main.xml.. what is fragment_main.xml? thank you!!

Comment: hihii ok, "or load the url into the WebView from the PlaceholderFragment" :)