# Error with setOnClickListener(this)

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have used the code that Eclipse creates by default and added a button with an OnClickListener.

The following code crashes at the last line where I use setOnClickListener(this).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button startStopButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        startStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startStopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

This is probably something trivial but I don't understand what the issue is. The onClick method is defined below if that is in any way relevant, but it does nothing right now.

Using onClick in the layout xml works, but I have read elsewhere that it is bad practice to use it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: surely startStopButton.setOnClickListener(this) should be replaced..

Comment: Stacktraces are your friend.

Comment: i think the button is null. can you check that the button is not null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Comment: May you implemented the interface method "onClick"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are loading a fragment

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
```

and into the `PlaceholderFragment()` doesn´t exist a reference of `startButton`

```
 startStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
```

your problem is similar to this post:

**[Unable to load url in webview (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735051/unable-to-load-url-in-webview-android/22735275#22735275)**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `startStopButton.setOnClickListener(this);`
with

```
startStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent("com.monster.android.activitylifecycle.SecndActivity");
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

You are passing this which is refering to object of current activity..instead you should pass object of annonymouse class View.OnClickListener which implements onclick() method..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line `implements OnClickListener` to `implements View.OnClickListener` :-)
Or as I see now.
Are you sure that the button is not in the XML layout file, which belongs to PlaceHolderFragment?

Answer (score 0):

Please implement the onclick() method.

```
public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.startButton)
{
    //type what you want to do here
}
}
```